# Chakra Host Samples does not execute JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, c#, win-universal-app, windows, chakra

I just started playing around with Windows Dev and please pardon me if this issue does not seem logical or legit to you.

I am trying these [Chakra Host samples on Microsoft GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Chakra-Samples/tree/master/Chakra%20Samples/JSRT%20Universal%20Windows%20Apps%20Hosting%20Samples/C%23) and when input js cond like `console.log` or `alert`, I get error like `'console' is undefined`.  Am I missing something obvious. I tried looking up but unfortunately could not find the relevant docs or code sample.

Any help/pointer is appreciated.
[image: Chakra Sample]

Comment: What's the `console` (the engine is running in the UWP app here)? The `console` you've used is a web browser/Node feature for example, and not part of JavaScript. You can expose your own methods/objects to be used by the JavaScript runtime.

Comment: I just thought of this as a JS interpreter. Could you please point to some docs or API guides or samples on how to write these features?

Comment: It's a JavaScript execution environment. I've posted an answer with some references that should help.

Answer (score 2):

The `console` is a web browser (and Node) feature. It doesn't exist within JavaScript. So, you need to add it (or something similar).

There's an example in the Win32 Edge/Chakra host code on Github that demonstrates how to add a callback function to the global namespace.

[Example callback for `Echo`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Chakra-Samples/blob/master/Chakra%20Samples/JSRT%20Win32%20Hosting%20Samples/Edge%20JSRT%20Samples/C%23/Program.cs#L121)

You should be able to do something similar. You can also [expose existing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249552.aspx#Windows) Windows runtime namespaces to Chakra.

```
    private static void DefineHostCallback(JavaScriptValue globalObject, string callbackName, JavaScriptNativeFunction callback, IntPtr callbackData)
    {
        var propertyId = JavaScriptPropertyId.FromString(callbackName);

        // Create a function
        var function = JavaScriptValue.CreateFunction(callback, callbackData);

        // Set the property
        globalObject.SetProperty(propertyId, function, true);
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I get the concept. I am asking for a little more help here - 

``I want to invoke/open a browser window from a native windows universal app and this is why I am looking into the Chakra Engine.`` 

Could you please tell me if this can be achieved via what you posted above? Also, could you point me to the correct API or write a sample code? I am way below novice when it comes to Windows Programming

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Launch a URL from your UWP app?

Comment: In a nutshell, yes. I want to be able to open a URL in browser window from a UWP app. 

Also, I have a JS fie that opens the url and the window as I require - If there is a way to somehow embed/execute that JS file from UWP, I assume that should work as well. 

Right now, the way I do on browser is I put a html button and execute the JS file and it will open another browse window. The end goal is to be able to open the URL in the browser window. It has to be a browser only.

Comment: Using the links and code in my answer you can expose a way from JavaScript to launch a URL.